# How to make paragraphed text appear in a multi-line textbox when a treenode is selected

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I reckon this is probably a simple thing to do but I can't seem to know how to pull it off as I am new to VB.Net.

On my form, I have a treeview control I have populated with nodes using the Nodes Collection TreeNode Editor. I also have a multi-line textbox. When a node is selected, some pre-defined text assigned to that particular node appears in my textbox.

What I want to achieve is for paragraphs of text with formatting, to be inputted into the textbox and not just single lines of text as shown in my code below.

For instance, when the user clicks a node titled 'Soccer', I would like a formatted body of text like:

“This is a sport.

It is a sport played between two teams of eleven players with a spherical ball.

It is played by 250 million players in over 200 countries.”

to appear in my textbox. Please how can I get the code to do this? I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. The code I am using at the moment is shown below. Thank you in advance.

```html
 Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
       
        Dim SelectedNode As TreeNode
        SelectedNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode
        If SelectedNode.Text = "Soccer" Then
            TextBox1.Text = "This is a sport." 'I would like to have paragraphed text appear in                                                      'textbox1 instead of a single line of text
        Else
            If SelectedNode.Text = "Moon" Then
                TextBox1.Text = "This is the name of a car." 'I would like to have paragraphed text                                                                'appear in textbox1 instead of a single                                                                'line of text
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `vbCrLf` to force text to a new line, two of them will leave a blank line. For example 'Dim soccerText As String = "This is a sport." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf "It is played.....".

Comment: ...or you could use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `vbCrLf`... or you could use `String.Format`... or you could use a `StringBuilder` and then `StringBuilder.AppendLine`... or...

Comment: @Blackwood - Ah ah! Thanks for the intellectual jolt! That was what I was looking for.

Comment: @JoshPart - Thanks for your suggestion. I appreciate your taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should add '\n' in end of your line.

Comment: I don't think that would do much in VB :)

Comment: @VladislavVazhenin - Thank for taking the time to help me.